# HL: Source flashlight not working

Tags: technical-issues, half-life-source

When I try to turn on the flashlight, it doesn't light anything up, and instead gives me lots of lag. It only lights up ragdolls, from what I've seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a somewhat common issue, and there are a few things that you can try to do in order to get this working.

1. **Try running these commands in the console:** (instructions for using the console below)

   - `r_dynamic 1`
   - `r_shadows 1`
   - `r_newflashlight 0`
2. **Try updating your video card drivers.** Some driver versions have had issues with Half-Life. (instructions for updating video card drivers below)
3. **Make sure that your computer (specifically your video card) meets the [minimum requirements](http://store.steampowered.com/app/280/)**. Consider checking in-game that DirectX 7/OpenGL 2.1 or higher is applied. You can look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT1Je.jpg) to see what the game has DirectX or OpenGL set to.

### Enabling the console:

[image]

Press tilde (`~`), located to the left of the `1` key to open the console once enabled.

### Updating your video card drivers:

For **Nvidia**: (Often named 'GeForce'. Recent cards are in a series of '8xxx', '9xxx', '2xx', '3xx', '4xx', '5xx', '6xx'.)

http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

For **Ati**: (Often named 'Radeon'. Recent cards are in a series of '3xxx', '4xxx', '5xxx', '6xxx', '7xxx'.)

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

For **Intel**: (Often referred to as embedded, onboard, or non-discrete.)

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/

Comment: This worked....